# Magento 1.9.1 WYSIWYG Editor Logs me out of Backend

Tags: magento-1.9, wysiwyg

each time I change a product description via WYSIWYG Editor, Submit the Change in the Popup Window and try to Save the article in Magento Backend, it Logs me out of the whole Backend, redirecting to the admin Login Site.

SSL / HTTPS is active and setup correctly. Seems like the Editor itself uses another session ID or cache Option than Magento itself.

Any idea to fix this?

Many thanks!